# Alert cuts long text in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

if an alert has too much text, instead of scrolling the text it is cut and even the buttons can be reached. Is this a bug? should I rise a report? how? I’m using Ionic 4 beta 12

Code:

```
  async showRules() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Rules',
      subHeader: `Brain Builder is up to date with the most recent research regarding IQ enhancement.
As the most recent research suggest, Brain Builder will increase the number of stimulus first (position, audio, color, etc.).
Once all stimuli have been mastered, the n-back will be increased.A blue square will be shown every three seconds, press the button ‘Position’ when you find that the actual position of the blue square matches with that of the previous one.
The position of the square is accompanied with the pronunciation of a number and the very same rule applies for the sound.
`,
      buttons: ['OK'],
      backdropDismiss: false
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Luis did you check that on simulator or actual device I think it will work on device with scrollable content and alert buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have placed the enormous content in `subheader` instead of `message`. Try:

```
 async showRules() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Rules',
      message: `Brain Builder is up to date with the most recent research regarding IQ enhancement.
As the most recent research suggest, Brain Builder will increase the number of stimulus first (position, audio, color, etc.).
Once all stimuli have been mastered, the n-back will be increased.A blue square will be shown every three seconds, press the button ‘Position’ when you find that the actual position of the blue square matches with that of the previous one.
The position of the square is accompanied with the pronunciation of a number and the very same rule applies for the sound.
`,
      buttons: ['OK'],
      backdropDismiss: false
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

The subheader is just the sub title and possibly not scrollable. Documentation [here](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert)